# How to write return type correctly according to return statement in python?

Tags: python, function, types, return, zip

I want to write a return type for a function for the complicated return statement

```
return tuple(sorted(
        tuple(zip(*(zip(*line) for line in lines.values()))),
        key=_get_line_origin_x,
    ))
```

`lines` represent  `lines: Dict[Tuple[int, graphanno.Node], List[Tuple[int, graphanno.Node]]] = {(reference_idx, reference): [(reference_idx, reference)]}`

I tried to write the return type, `Tuple[Sequence[Tuple[int, Node]], ...]`

Comment: @testfile sorry did not get you. Can you ellaborate ?

Comment: Can you include the whole function for clarity?